# Riemann zeta for real argument between 0 and 1 using Mellin, with short asymptotic expansion

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mellin-transform

The following would appear to be true.

For real $0 < \sigma < 1,$ we seem to have a very satisfying sum minus integral limit,
$$  \zeta(\sigma)  \; \; = \; \;  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\sigma}   \right) - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma} \; \; . $$

A little more detail in these examples:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k}   \right) - 2 \sqrt n - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt n} + \frac{1}{24 n^{3/2}} \; \; = \; \; \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx -1.460354508809586  $$

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[3] k}   \right) - \frac{3 n^{2/3}}{2} - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt[3] n} + \frac{1}{36 n^{4/3}} \; \; = \; \; \zeta \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \approx -0.973360248350782  $$

So, are the above items **really really** true (rather than wishful thinking), and, if so, given $0 < \sigma < 1,$ what real numbers $A = A(\sigma), B = B(\sigma),$  make the short asymptotic expansion below correct?

$$ \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\sigma}   \right) - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma} - A n^{-\sigma} + B n^{-1-\sigma} \; \; = \; \;  \zeta(\sigma) \; \; + \; \;  O(n^{-2-\sigma}) \; \; ? $$

Here is an estimate of $\zeta\left( \frac{1}{5} \right)$ using Daniel's expansion as far as the $3+\sigma$ term, ignoring $5+\sigma$: $$ \zeta(\sigma) =\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\sigma}   \right) - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma} - \frac{1}{2 n^\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{12 n^{1 + \sigma}} - \frac{\sigma (1 + \sigma)(2 + \sigma)}{720 n^{3+\sigma}} + O \left( \frac{1}{n^{5 + \sigma}} \right)$$
I think it will let me fit 33 lines in a "code" window without introducing a scroll bar.

```
    1   1                   -0.7340666666666666   
    2   1.870550563296124   -0.7339263390330826   
    3   2.673292125056355   -0.7339216399387463   
    4   3.431150408311554   -0.7339210905379737   
    5   4.155930071989249   -0.7339209776636304   
    6   4.854757190760828   -0.7339209455319796   
    7   5.532368104161309   -0.7339209342063361   
    8   6.192122059547756   -0.7339209295629763   
    9   6.836516074525011   -0.7339209274322004   
   10   7.467473419005204   -0.7339209263652269   
   11   8.086517339689049   -0.7339209257924113   
   12   8.694881681582254   -0.7339209254668952   
   13   9.293584537123753   -0.7339209252729478   
   14   9.883479099480143   -0.7339209251526775   
   15   10.46528985863283   -0.7339209250754953   
   16   11.03963903613135   -0.7339209250244763   
   17   11.60706632180293   -0.7339209249898626   
   18   12.16804389452603   -0.7339209249658375   
   19   12.72298804735438   -0.7339209249488197   
   20   13.27226831900744   -0.7339209249365428   
   21   13.81621476189632   -0.7339209249275397   
   22   14.35512379575268   -0.7339209249208374   
   23   14.8892629725969    -0.7339209249157863   
   24   15.41887489312131   -0.7339209249119263   
   25   15.94418045400206   -0.733920924908948   
   26   16.46538156214071   -0.7339209249066238   
   27   16.98266342011249   -0.7339209249047942   
   28   17.49619646365717   -0.7339209249033369   
   29   18.00613801451264   -0.7339209249021712   
   30   18.51263369862476   -0.7339209249012291   
   31   19.01581866962328   -0.733920924900462   
   32   19.51581866962328   -0.7339209248998368   
   33   20.0127509533112    -0.7339209248993227
```

[image]

Comment: actually, when doing 1/2, I tried to get the next term and it kept coming out zero. I gave up. However, it allows for the possibility that the $O$ term may not always be what I indicate above...

Comment: Happy New Year Will.  I assume that you used The Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.  Recall that if the original sum begins at, say $m$, then the integral term has $m-1$ as the lower limit.

Comment: @MarkViola, no, I adjusted terms in a short asymptotic expansion without being entirely sure that the limit was as advertised. I minimized the tail sum...

Comment: Will, application of the EMSF gets you the coveted result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is  a standard technique  that produces the  complete asymptotic
expansion  for this  sum and  many  others like  it, which  is to  use
harmonic sums and Mellin transforms.

Introduce the telescoping sum where $0\lt\sigma\lt 1$

$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \left(\frac{1}{k^\sigma}-
\frac{1}{(x+k)^\sigma}\right).$$

This sum has the property that

$$S(n) = \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{1}{p^\sigma},$$

so that $S(n)$ is the value we are looking for.

Re-write the sum as follows:

$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^\sigma}
 \left(1-\frac{1}{(x/k+1)^\sigma}\right).$$

The sum term is harmonic and  may be evaluated by inverting its Mellin
transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{k^\sigma}, 
\quad \mu_k = \frac{1}{k} \quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{(1+x)^\sigma}.$$

It follows that
$$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^\sigma} \times k^s
= \zeta(\sigma-s)$$
which has fundamental strip $\sigma-s > 1$ or $s < \sigma-1.$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{(1+x)^\sigma}\right) x^{s-1} dx$$

which is immediately seen to be a beta function integral with value
$$g^*(s) = - \frac{1}{\Gamma(\sigma)} \Gamma(s)\Gamma(\sigma-s)$$

and  fundamental strip  $\langle -1,  0  \rangle.$ We  check that  the
abscissa of  convergence of the  zeta function  term is right  in this
strip as required. It follows that  the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the
harmonic sum $S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) =
- \frac{1}{\Gamma(\sigma)} \Gamma(s)\Gamma(\sigma-s)
\zeta(\sigma-s).$$

The Mellin inversion integral here is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{\sigma-1-\varepsilon-i\infty}
^{\sigma-1-\varepsilon+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$

which we  evaluate by  shifting it  to the right  for an  expansion at
infinity.

First  treat the  pole from  the zeta  function term  at $s=\sigma-1$,
which has

$$\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=\sigma-1) =
-\frac{1}{\Gamma(\sigma)} \Gamma(\sigma-1)\Gamma(1)
\times -1 \times x^{1-\sigma}
= -\frac{1}{1-\sigma} x^{1-\sigma}.$$

For the pole at $s=0$ from the simple gamma function term we obtain

$$\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=0) = 
-\frac{1}{\Gamma(\sigma)} \Gamma(\sigma) \zeta(\sigma)
= -\zeta(\sigma).$$

For the pole at $s=\sigma$ from the compound gamma function term we obtain

$$\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=\sigma) =
 -\frac{1}{\Gamma(\sigma)} \Gamma(\sigma) \times -1 \times\zeta(0)
\times \frac{1}{x^\sigma}
= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{x^\sigma}.$$

The remaining poles are at $s = q+\sigma$ where $q\ge 1$ and contribute

$$\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=q+\sigma) =
-\frac{1}{\Gamma(\sigma)} \Gamma(\sigma+q) 
\frac{(-1)^{q+1}}{q!} \zeta(-q) \frac{1}{x^{q+\sigma}}
\\ = - \prod_{p=0}^{q-1} (p+\sigma) \times
 \frac{(-1)^{q+1}}{q!} (-1)^q \frac{B_{q+1}}{q+1} \frac{1}{x^{q+\sigma}}
= {q+\sigma-1\choose q} 
\frac{B_{q+1}}{q+1}  \frac{1}{x^{q+\sigma}}.$$

The  zero   values  of  the  Bernoulli   numbers  correctly  represent
cancelation of  the gamma function poles  by the trivial zeros  of the
zeta function.

Setting $x=n$  and observing that  the shift  to the right  produces a
minus sign we obtain the following asymptotic expansion:

$$S(n) = \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{1}{p^\sigma}
\\ \sim \frac{1}{1-\sigma} n^{1-\sigma}
+ \zeta(\sigma) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n^\sigma}
- \sum_{q\ge 1} {q+\sigma-1\choose q}
\frac{B_{q+1}}{q+1}  \frac{1}{n^{q+\sigma}}.$$

Actually computing the Bernoulli number terms we get for the example
by OP with $\sigma=1/3$ the expansion

$$3/2\,{n}^{2/3}+\zeta  \left( 1/3 \right) 
+1/2\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{n}}}
-1/36\,{n}^{-4/3}+{\frac {7}{4860\,{n}^{10/3}}}
\\-{\frac {13}{26244\,{n}^{16/3}}}
+{\frac {247}{590490}{n}^{-{\frac {22}{3}}}}
-{\frac {6175}{9565938}{n}^{-{\frac {28}{3}}}}
\\+{\frac {406999}{258280326}{n}^{-{\frac {34}{3}}}}
-{\frac {12966835}{2324522934}{n}^{-{\frac {40}{3}}}}+\cdots$$

This    [MSE    link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79115/)
points to a series of similar calculations.

Answer (score 5):

The Euler-Maclaurin formula gives the asymptotic expansion

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{\sigma}} = \zeta(\sigma) + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{1-\sigma} \binom{1-\sigma}{k} B_k n^{1-\sigma-k}\,.
\end{equation}

Thus $A = -B_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $B = -\frac{(-1)\sigma}{2}B_2 = \frac{\sigma}{12}$.

Taking a few more terms, we get

\begin{align}
\zeta(\sigma) &= \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^{\sigma}} - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma} - \frac{1}{2n^{\sigma}} + \frac{\sigma}{12 n^{1+\sigma}} - \frac{\sigma(1+\sigma)(2+\sigma)}{720 n^{3+\sigma}} \\
&\qquad+ \frac{\sigma(1+\sigma)(2+\sigma)(3+\sigma)(4+\sigma)}{30240n^{5+\sigma}} + O(n^{-7-\sigma})\,.
\end{align}

Comment: So the part I think of as the integral being subtracted off is your $k=0?$ Pushing my luck, what is the very next term, $C n^{-2 - \sigma} \; ?$

Comment: Yes, $k = 0$ gives $\frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}$. The next term corresponds to $k = 3$, and conveniently the odd-indexed Bernoulli numbers except $B_1$ all vanish, so $C = 0$. After that, $k = 4$ with $B_4 = -\frac{1}{30}$ produces $\frac{\sigma(\sigma+1)(\sigma+2)}{720}n^{-(3+\sigma)}$.

Comment: It must be a $-$, $\dotsc - \frac{\sigma(1+\sigma)(2+\sigma)}{720n^{3+\sigma}}$. And I just noticed that you wrote $-An^{-\sigma} + Bn^{-1-\sigma}$, with different signs. I thought both had a minus, so my value for $B$ has the wrong sign. Fixing that.

Comment: $$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\sigma}   \right) - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma} - \frac{1}{2 n^\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{12 n^{1 + \sigma}} - \frac{\sigma (1 + \sigma)(2 + \sigma)}{720 n^{3+\sigma}}$$

Comment: And I've also added the next term.

Comment: But now I have a rendez-vous with my mattress.

Comment: Assuming all the analytic continuations are valid, the $A$ value can easily be obtained by approximating $\int_{k+1}^{k+2}(x^{-\sigma}-(k+1)^{-\sigma})dx$ using the trapezoid approximation, summing from $n$ to $\infty$, and noticing that all the terms other than the first telescope. $B$ can be gotten in a similar way, using Simpson's rule approximations for the error integrals, but you have to add the integral starting with an odd number $n$ to that starting with $n+1$ to get obvious telescoping.  Fortunately, the difference  of the two error integrals is easy to determine in closed form.

Comment: I'm sorry but I believe that there is a typo, I don't understand the notation $B =-\frac{(-1)\sigma}{2}B_2$, because I think that yours $B$ are Bernoulli numbers, I don't know where were the subscripts.

Comment: @user243301 The $B_k$ are  Bernoulli numbers (I use the variant with $B_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$), the $B$ without subscript is from the expansion in the question, $$\Biggl(\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^{\sigma}}\Biggr) - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma} - An^{-\sigma} + Bn^{-1-\sigma}\,.$$

Comment: Daniel, your last formula in the answer is missing the Bernoulli "zero" term, $ \; \;  - \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1 - \sigma },$ which I do see in your comment just before this.

Comment: @WillJagy Oops. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hi Daniel.  I hope that you're doing well.  In the first expression in your post, the first term is $\zeta(\sigma)$.  How does one know that the constant term is in fact the Riemann Zeta function evaluated at $\sigma$ without a bit of explanation?  For example, one could rely on the analytic continuation of the function $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-\sigma} -\frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}-\frac12 n^{-\sigma}$ from $\text{Re}(\sigma)>1$ to $\text{Re}(\sigma)>-1$ with $\sigma\ne 1$.  What did you have in mind here?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed true. In fact, this formula can be derived from the [Euler summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) with $f(x)=x^{-s}$ with $0<s<1$. We have

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{x^s}&=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t^s}-s\int\frac{t-[t]}{t^{s+1}}dt+1-\frac{x-[x]}{x^s} \\ 
 &=\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}-\frac{1}{1-s}+1-s\int_1^\infty\frac{t-[t]}{t^{s+1}}dt+O(x^{-s}).
\end{align*}$$

If we take the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ we find that

$$1-\frac{1}{1-s}-s\int_1^\infty\frac{t-[t]}{t^{s+1}}dt=\zeta(s)$$

so we then have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}\right)=\zeta(s),\;\;0<s<1$$

as desired.

Note that $[t]$ is the greatest integer function. This proof can be found in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol.