# Alternating summation and subtraction of square roots

Tags: radicals

I encountered a problem, to find the integer part of: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}} +...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99} + \sqrt{100}}$$.

I multiplied the conjugate of each denominator.  Meaning, for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}$, I multiply $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.  I get $\sqrt{100} - \sqrt{99} + \sqrt{98} - \sqrt{97} + ... + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}$.  I am stuck here.  How do I simplify this?  Or is it that my method is wrong?

Comment: Thats what I did... you get $\sqrt{100} - \sqrt{99} + \sqrt{98} - \sqrt{97} + ... + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}$

Comment: And it is a - b @Wauzl

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, sorry. I deleted my initial comment

Comment: It is telescoping.

Comment: Well I think the fact terms differing by one are paired close suggests telescoping..

Comment: But I do not see how the terms can cancel out... @ClaudeLeibovici do you have any ideas?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281+%2B+√2%29+%2B1%2F%28√3%2B√4%29%2B...1%2F%28√99%2B√100%29) can't find a general term.

Comment: I think $\sqrt{100} - \sqrt{99} + \sqrt{98} - \sqrt{97} + \cdots + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}$ may be the answer.  Its value $4.6323951\ldots$ does not suggest anything obvious to me

Comment: If the largest term is $\sqrt{2n}$, so here $n=50$, then the sum is approximately $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}-0.38$ when $n$ is large

Comment: Hmm perhaps can someone provide a solution that may be a close estimate?  @Henry can you tell me how you got $4.6323951\ldots$?

Comment: @XcoderX in R: as expected `n <- 1:50; sum(1/(sqrt(2*n-1)+sqrt(2*n)))` gives the same result as `n <- 1:50; sum(sqrt(2*n)-sqrt(2*n-1))`

Comment: @Henry Your $-0.38$ can be identified as $\displaystyle(2\sqrt{2}-1)\,\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an approximation, we might start (using a not generally adopted, but not unfamiliar notation) with$$H^{(-1/2)}_n=1 + \sqrt{2} + \ldots + \sqrt{n}=\frac{2}{3}n^{3/2} + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} + \zeta\left(-\frac12\right)+o(1),$$ mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/how-closely-can-we-estimate-sum-i-0n-sqrti?noredirect=1&lq=1) ($\zeta$ is the famous [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)).
Then, $$\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{2n-1}\pm\ldots=-H^{(-1/2)}_{2n}+2\sqrt{2}\,H^{(-1/2)}_n=\frac12\sqrt{2n}+(2\sqrt{2}-1)\,\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)+o(1).$$
For $n=50$, the main term would be $\displaystyle5+(2\sqrt{2}-1)\,\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)=4.619895\ldots$, while the original sum is $4.6323951\ldots$, as @Henry pointed out, already, $\displaystyle(2\sqrt{2}-1)\,\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)=-0.380105\ldots$ being slightly more accurate. The error (of the order $O(1/n)$) is no surprise.

Comment: Once again, somebody is happy that votes are anonymous, but how would that stop me laughing at you? The software of this site will stop you to make this a campaign. BTW, a downvote (fair or not) costs me just 2 points.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: I think I know who you are, but let's pretend I don't. You are welcome to apply your own standards, but this post is very much ok. To the point that I am hard pressed to believe that the downvote is not personal. An ok answer to an ok question. What's there not to like? Bring in your sense of humor, step back and take a fresh look at a post. It is difficult to put past differences in the past, I have hard time doing that myself (which is why I won't do anything yet), but we should do our best. Both you and I.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree this is a great answer.

Comment: @XcoderX Don't you worry, the moderator doesn't suspect *you*. I'm glad you like my answer, though it doesn't help you, strictly speaking: I've just seen in the comments that you're supposed to find an approximation *without a calculator*. And most people wouldn't know how to compute $\zeta(-1/2)$ even *with* a calculator. So I'm working on estimates amenable to pencil-paper-work, but that will take some time.

Comment: Haha, I did not think that.  I just have that kind of feeling where you get downvoted for no apparent reason...  Back to the question, estimates like root 2 can be easily made.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand  $(2\sqrt{2}-1)\,\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)=-0.380105\ldots$. How did you find $\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)$ ? Sorry again for such a basic question.

Comment: In my answer, I've linked a related question, since I didn't want to repeat what's written in more detail, there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/how-closely-can-we-estimate-sum-i-0n-sqrti

Comment: That doesn't answer my question of how did you find the value of  $\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)$ ?

Comment: @user45914123 Sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought you meant the symbolic, not the numerical value. Well, that's easy, and free: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta(-0.5) Normally, I'd use GP, but with Wolfram Alpha, it was quicker in that case. Of course, I could also transform it to the argument $3/2$ with the famous functional equation, and calculate that numerically with an alternating series.

Comment: Can you show the other method ? Is it better than calculating all the square roots by hand ?

Comment: @user45914123 Sure I can, but that would be off topic, here. Ask the question, if you want to know,

Comment: I can but I am afraid that I will get downvotes cause I am nothing of my work to show. By alternating series do you mean to calculate 4 or 5 terms of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^{3/2}$; won't that be very difficult by hand ?

Comment: That's why I said "if  you want to know". It's your decision. "Alternating series" means exactly that, an alternating series, you actually can express $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^{3/2}$ in terms of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}1/k^{3/2}$ And that's enough, moderators already complained about a private conversation, and they're right. If you have a question, ask it, but not in another person's question.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Well it is your answer, you should improve it. The question is about finding the integer part without a calculator. So I asked how you approximated that fancy term, to which you said you used a calculator. Then I asked you to show the numerical method, that you won't do. I fail to see how this is an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

We want to find the integer part of 
$\sum_{x=1}^{50} f(x)$
where
$f(x) = \sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2x-1}$.

For decreasing $f(x)$, 
$$\int_a^{b+1} f(x) \; dx < \sum_{x=a}^b f(x) < \int_{a-1}^b f(x) \; dx$$
(It may help to make a sketch to see this.)

It's easier to work with the sum from $x=2$ to $50$ instead of $x=1$ to 50 because $f(x)$ is not defined when $x=0$.  We can adjust for the missing $x=1$ term later.

By elementary calculus, 
$$\int f(x) \; dx = \frac{1}{3} (2x)^{3/2} - \frac{1}{3} (2x-1)^{3/2} + C$$
so
$$\int_2^{51} f(x) \; dx < \sum_{x=2}^{50} f(x) < \int_{1}^{50} f(x) \; dx$$
yields
$$4.10 < \sum_{x=2}^{50} f(x) < 4.38$$
Now to adjust for the missing $x=1$ term.  Since $$\sum_{x=2}^{50} f(x) + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1} = \sum_{x=1}^{50} f(x)$$
we have
$$4.10 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1} < \sum_{x=1}^{50} f(x) < 4.38 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}$$
which yields
$$4.51 < \sum_{x=1}^{50} f(x) < 4.79$$
so the integer part of the sum is $\boxed{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt n +\sqrt {n+1}} = \sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt {n}$$

Therefore the  dsire sum is $ A-B$ where,

$$A= \sqrt 100+\sqrt 98 +....+\sqrt 2 = 338.047...$$ and 
$$B=\sqrt 99+\sqrt 97 +....+\sqrt 1 = 333.415....$$
Thus [A-B]=4

Comment: Ideally, that would be the answer, but unfortunately I cannot use a calculator.